# Remove cell borders in table in Word document (OpenXml.Wordprocessing)

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` to add a table in a Word document. What I need is to remove the border of the first 4(/6) cells in the last 3(/N) rows of the table. These rows are added like:

```
t.Append(new TableRow(
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text()))),
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text()))),
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text()))),
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text()))),
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Total:")))),
    new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(priceTotal.ToString()))))
    ));
```

How do I set the `TableCellBorders`? I've tried a few things like:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellBorders.LeftBorder.Size.Value = 0;
cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellBorders.RightBorder.Size.Value = 0;
cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellBorders.TopBorder.Size.Value = 0;
cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellBorders.BottomBorder.Size.Value = 0;
```

However, everything that I've tried returns `System.NullReferenceException`. What is the proper way of removing the cell borders?

Comment: Probably because the borders are defined under your style sheet..

Comment: There are two ways you can define Table borders in a Word document. One way is to define the borders in a Table element, and another way is to define the borders in TableCell elements.

Comment: I want to define them for each TableCell, since they differ from one to another. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a table in word with no borders like this:

```
public static void CreateTable(string fileName)
{
    // Use the file name and path passed in as an argument 
    // to open an existing Word 2007 document.

    using (WordprocessingDocument doc
        = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        // Create an empty table.
        Table table = new Table();

        // Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
        TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
            new TableBorders(
                new TopBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                    new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                },
                new BottomBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                },
                new LeftBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                },
                new RightBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                },
                new InsideHorizontalBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                },
                new InsideVerticalBorder()
                {
                    Val =
                        new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                }
            )
        );

        // Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
        table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);

        // Create a row.
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();

        // Create a cell.
        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();

        // Specify the width property of the table cell.
        tc1.Append(new TableCellProperties(
            new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2400" }));

        // Specify the table cell content.
        tc1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("some text"))));

        // Append the table cell to the table row.
        tr.Append(tc1);

        // Create a second table cell by copying the OuterXml value of the first table cell.
        TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(tc1.OuterXml);

        // Append the table cell to the table row.
        tr.Append(tc2);

        // Append the table row to the table.
        table.Append(tr);

        // Append the table to the document.
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
    }
}
```

Customize and optimize it, to your needs :)

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I had to use `Nil` instead of `Null`. Idk why, but that is what fixed my issue. However, I'll mark your answer, since it really helped me and pushed me in the right direction! Thanks!
`new RightBorder()
{
    Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Nil),
}`

Comment: Any idea on how you'd remove borders from an existing table?

Comment: @mattpm have you tried to access the `Table` element and set new Border properties?